# Is it "PhD at [subject]"?

Tags: phrases

If I say

> "Doctor Strange is a PhD at Mystic Arts"

would this sentence be right?

Comment: "Doctor Strange is a PhD in Mystic Arts" is valid syntax.  Whether it's "right" is not for me to judge.

Comment: Tachanka you for answering, LOL, I forgot to put "grammatically," in front of "right"

Comment: And you forgot how to spell "boy".  And you forgot to capitalize Doctor Strange's name.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean: "Mystic Arts" is the subject of the PhD studies?

> Doctor Strange holds a PhD in mystic arts

Or is "Mystic Arts" the name of the university where the PhD was awarded?

> Doctor Strange earned PhD from Mystic Arts U